# Passing $scope data to $stateProvider.state resolve

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

I have a parent state app.teams.show which stores "team" in $scope.data.team. Within a controller I have access to $scope.data.team and therefore $scope.data.team.organization_id.

How can I access $scope.data.team.organization_id inside the resolve?

```
.state('app.teams.show.games.add', {
    url: '/add',
    templateUrl: 'templates/schedule/games/add.html',
    controller: 'GamesAddCtrl',
    resolve:{
        org: function($http, $scope){
            return $http.get('http://api.example.com/orgs/'+$scope.data.team.organization_id, {cache: true});
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: You cannot. It looks like you need to rethink your architecture.

Comment: To be a little more specific, it sounds like the concept of *team* in your application is a *resource* that should be exposed by a *service* rather than simply a variable in one controller's scope.

Comment: any suggestions? It didn't seem like something that should be impossible. I used $stateParams to get the team and that worked fine, this depends on some information that's returned by the first one. 

It works if I move it into the controller instead of here, is that a reasonable solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are trying to achieve is the correct solution.
In your situation, I would probably just pass `$scope.data.team.organization_id` as a parameter to your state and use it in the resolve block.

```
    .state('app.teams.show.games.add', {
        url: '/add/:orgId', // or /add?orgId or :orgId/add
        templateUrl: 'templates/schedule/games/add.html',
        controller: 'GamesAddCtrl',
        resolve:{
            org: function($http, $stateParams){
                return $http.get('http://api.example.com/orgs/'+$stateParams.orgId, {cache: true});
            }
        }

})
```